# CSS not getting included in PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to include my CSS with `!important` tag in PrimeFaces.
I have not set any particular style but I added the CSS to my XHTML page like,

```
<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="/abc/WebContent/resources/myStyleSheet.css"/>
</h:body>
```

When I am checking the Source in browser using "View page source", I don't see my CSS included at all.

Can somebody pls help !

Comment: <h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
 <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="/abc/WebContent/resources/myStyleSheet.css" />
...
...
</h:body>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11988418/1391249

Comment: If your css folder is in under WebContent/resources/ already then you don't need to give full path directly call with name only like, <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="myStyleSheet.css"/>